# Rails 4, img_tag as form_for control?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to build a form where the user is able to pick an avatar image for his user profile. I have a table named avatars(which has id(INT) and url(string), and another named users(with a bunch of stuff, and img(INT)).

I want to create a preview of all the avatar images, and then enable the user to click on the one he wants to pick it (preferably this would highlight the image border), and then write the avatar id into the user table under img. I think I've set up the proper associations, but now I've hit a wall on how to handle on click events on the img_tag. Is this the correct way to do this, and if not how should I be doing it?

my view so far:

```
<div class="col-lg-6">  
    <%= form_for @user do |f| %>
        <%if @user.errors.any? %>
            <% for message in @user.errors.full_messages %>
            <div class="alert alert-danger"><%= message %></div>
            <% end %>
        <% end %>
        <%= f.label :username %>
        <%= f.text_field :username, class:'form-control', placeholder:'MightyWizard5578' %><br />
        <%= f.label :email %>
        <%= f.text_field :email, class:'form-control', placeholder:'example@topdeckandwreck.com' %><br /> 

</div>

<div class="col-lg-12">
    <strong>Pick your avatar:</strong><br />    
    <% @avatars.each do |avatar| %>
    <%= image_tag(avatar.url, height: '75', width: '75') %>
    <% end %>
</div><br />

<div class="col-lg-6">
    <%= f.label :bio %>
    <%= f.text_area :bio, class:'form-control', placeholder:'Tell us a bit about yourself!' %><br /> 
</div>
    <% end %>
```

my controller:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  ... 

  def edit
    @avatars = Avatar.all
    @user = current_user
  end

  def update
  end

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:username, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :img, :bio, :auth_token)    
  end
end
```

application controller:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  helper_method :current_user

  private
    def current_user
        @current_user ||= User.find_by_auth_token!(cookies[:auth_token]) if cookies[:auth_token]
    end
end
```

associations

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :avatar
end

class Avatar < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :users
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what is done in rails:

```
<div class="col-lg-12">
    <strong>Pick your avatar:</strong><br />    
    <% @avatars.each do |avatar| %>
        <label>
             <%= f.radio_button :avatar, avatar.id %>
             <%= image_tag(avatar.url, height: '75', width: '75') %>
        </label>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

So you can pick avatar from the list. Everything else (like hiding radio button, highlighting border and so on) is done in CSS

Comment: how do I look for the radio button selected event (or it's equivalent in rails) with rails or sass (in order to change the image style when selected)? Other than that your anwser works perfectly.

Comment: pseudo class :checked should do the trick. like `input:checked{...}`.  Of course, the selector should be more complex, because you don't want to style all of your inputs this way :) Plan 'B' is to use javascript for this

Comment: yeh, I guess I can always just write a simple javascript onclick event that changes the image css :) For now what matters is that the values get written into the database correctly, I'll worry about style later. Thanks for the help